# Logging using Log4j.properties in HTML custom format

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I need help editing the output of the Apache Log4j file.
I am using the html layout to save the logs created. Here's my log4j.properties code:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILEALL, FILEMAIN

log4j.appender.FILEMAIN=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILEMAIN.File=${logfileall.name}
log4j.appender.FILEMAIN.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.FILEMAIN.Threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.FILEALL=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILEALL.File=${logfilemain.name}
log4j.appender.FILEALL.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.FILEALL.Threshold=WARN
```

This creates a log file like this
[image]

I am confused as to how to change the output format.

I want the Time column to show a Timestamp in the format HH:mm:ss.S Format and I don't want the Thread column,

Also If possible, I  would like to rename the category to something like classpath.

Please help, how should I modify my Log4j.properties file for getting the above things done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only change the following options for [`org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/HTMLLayout.html):

```
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.Title=HTML Layout Demo
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.LocationInfo=true
```

By the way, you could do extend this [class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.log4j/com.springsource.org.apache.log4j/1.2.15/org/apache/log4j/HTMLLayout.java) and override the methods

```
public String format(LoggingEvent)
public String getHeader()
```

The first method get the HTML code for every event (e.g. a new row in the table). The second method get the HTML  for the *header* (from the `DOCTYPE` declaration to the table header row, e. g. `<thead>...</thead><tbody>`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your HTML Layout with a pattern layout using a custom pattern that dictates your preferred layout.

Answer (score 0):

Like Paul Vargas suggested, you need to build a custom layout that extends the `org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout`.

Looking inside the [code of the HTMLLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/org/apache/log4j/HTMLLayout.java#HTMLLayout), you will see inside the `format` method that time column doesn't allow any formatting:

```
 ...
 sbuf.append("<td>");
 sbuf.append(event.timeStamp - LoggingEvent.getStartTime());
 sbuf.append("</td>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
```

Formatting for thread is done this way:

```
 ...
 String escapedThread = Transform.escapeTags(event.getThreadName());
 sbuf.append("<td title=\"" + escapedThread + " thread\">");
 sbuf.append(escapedThread);
 sbuf.append("</td>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
 ...
```